# Calculations with Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Hey, need help to setup calculations in Rails3.

First off, I should write the logic in my model right? (transaction)

Then, let's assume I want to insert subtotal and total into the Db. What approach are you recommending?
Here is what I would do as a starting point.

In my model: Subtotal = amount

```
def subtotal
  @subtotal = :amount #table column
end
```

In my model: total = subtotal + tax

```
def total
 @total = :subtotal + :tax #again referring to table column
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably create subtotal and total attributes (include these in a create_ or change_table migration) and then set them in a callback like 'before_save.'

See:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#callbacks-overview

Comment: If I define callbacks then I won't be able to AJAX live update based on input. Yes/No?